# views_embed_view() ignores template file using Ajax

Tags: views, 9

I have a view shown in two ways. Once I show it as a normal block and one time using `views_embed_view()` in combination with Ajax.

For the regular block I created a `views-view-list.html.twig` template in my theme adding a `div` wrapper. My styling is based on this added div.

For the embedded block, this `views-view-list.html.twig` block is ignored and therefor the styling is off.

Using `views_embed_view()` inside a `preprocess` does work the way you'd expect, but using it with Ajax ignores the templates.

How can I make sure the template is not ignored, or is there a way to add another template that is seen when embedding the view?

I have a custom module *my_view_ajax*

I attach the js file in my *.module* file:

```
function my_view_ajax_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  //check content type
  if ($node->getType() == 'article' || $node->getType() == 'issue' ) {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'my_view_ajax/my_view_ajax__js';
  }
}
```

In my *.js* file I use Ajax to get my views block.

```
const routing_url = '/custom/ajax/articles';
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: routing_url,
  data: 'nid='+nid,
  dataType: 'html',
  async: true,
  complete: function (data) {
    $containerContent.empty().html(data.responseText);

    $containerContent.fadeIn();
    $ajaxLoader.fadeOut();
  }
});
```

In my `routing.yml` I create the Ajax path

```
my_view_ajax.articles:
  path: '/custom/ajax/articles'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Articles'
    _controller: '\Drupal\my_view_ajax\Controller\viewsajaxController::issueArticles'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

And finally in my `viewsajaxController.php`

```
namespace Drupal\my_view_ajax\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;
use \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class viewsajaxController extends ControllerBase {
  public function issueArticles() {
    $nid = 11;

    $markup = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render(views_embed_view('ccr_overview', 'block_articles_view', $nid));
    return new Response($markup);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the case as follow.

1.Added following structure in views-view-table--articles.html.twig

```
<div class="example-template">
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set titletxt = '' %}
  {% set viewnod = '' %}
  {% set editnode = '' %}
    {% for key, column in row.columns %}
      {% for field in column.fields %}                                    
        {% for content in column.content %}
          {% if field == 'title' %}
             {% set titletxt = content.field_output %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if field == 'view-node' %}
             {% set viewnod = content.field_output %}
          {% endif %}              
          {% if field == 'edit-node' %}
             {% set editnode = content.field_output %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    <div>
      <h3>
        {{titletxt}}
      </h3>
      <div>
        {{viewnod}}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{editnode}}
      </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

2. In node--article.html.twig embed following view

   ```
    <div class="relatedarticles">
      <h2>Articles From Block View</h2>
      {% if articles %}
        {{ articles }}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
   ```
3. in fluffiness.theme add as follow

   function fluffiness_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
   $relatedArticles = views_embed_view('articles', 'block_1');
   $variables['articles'] = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($relatedArticles);
   }

Then i noticed in node view mode, structure with template of view is rendered as follow.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found out. Because of your test that the problem is in using views embed in combination with Ajax. I updated my question with some extra information.